# open native select pop-up in android with js

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm developing android and ios app with phonegap, so i have a select and i want to open it with js, on ios simply focusing element works nice, but in android it does nothing, simulating click on select also gave no result, maybe there are some plugin for that?

Comment: How are you simulating the `click`?

Comment: Have you tried the `create/init/dispatchEvent` method [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)

Comment: Yeah, i tryed this also, still no luck with this, here is code example:          var element =  document.getElementById($('section.page_cart select:first').attr('id'))
      var o =  document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      o.initEvent("click", true, false);
      element.dispatchEvent(o);

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference, but I think mouse events require more init parameters `o.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false,  false,  0, null)`

Comment: this code also gives no result, i suggest it needs native plugin to make this feature avalible, seems like android browser blocks js fake events (i think the reason is security), but there are an alternative way that breaks layout but makes selection avalible, js imitation of ios like select wheel http://marinovdh.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/use-the-iphone-uipickerview-control-as-a-selectbox-on-your-website-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly i found a plugin for this issue, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/kidino/phonegap-alertdialoglist-plugin)